# Where does Blender install on Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, apt, paths, blender

I'm trying to put some export scripts into Blender but I simply cannot find the installation path!

I'm using the latest versions of both Ubuntu and Blender, which I have installed with `apt-get install`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blender scripts will go to `/usr/lib/blender/scripts/addons/`

P.S.-`which` is the command for finding the path of the executables. e.g. `which blender`. However, if you have Synaptic package manager, it's easy to find all installed files by going to package-properties > **Installed Files**. And also [Ubuntu package search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/blender/filelist) ;)

Comment: for Ubuntu 15.10 (and also possibly previous releases), the path is /usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/

Comment: found here in the docs --> https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html#platform-dependent-paths

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use the following command:

```
$ whereis blender
```

so in case you installed the program with "snap", then you can correctly locate the file

Comment: `whereis` can return multiple paths and the user may not be able to decide the correct. `which` suggested in above answer is preferred. Refer https://benohead.com/blog/2013/04/16/linux-which-vs-whereis/#:~:text=So%20this%20basically%20means%20that,are%20not%20in%20the%20path.